# How do I output a table to a txt file using tsql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I output a table to a txt file using tsql? I don't want to use DTS or SSIS in this instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

```
bcp MyDb.MySchema.Mytable out myTable.dat -T -c
```

- *out* can be replace with *queryout* if using an sql query, or *in* if loading data in.
- -T windows authentication, replace with -u and -p for sql auth
- -c outputs as text instead of binary
- -r is the row terminator option
- -t os tje field terminator option
- -S to specify a non default server

thats about all the really usefull options for exporting i think.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the most common answer from a Google search:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "SELECT TOP 5 CUSTOMERID FROM Northwind.dbo.Customers" queryout "c:\text.txt" -c -T -x'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to redirect your `SQL Server Management Studio` output to a file.

Answer (score 3):

I do this all the time with SQLCMD mode.  Here is an example:

```
-----------------------------
--Generate State seeds
-----------------------------

-- This is the path and file where you want the scripts to land.
:setvar OutDir "C:\Dev\Sandbox\GenTest\Scripts\"
:setvar OutFile "dbo.State.seed.sql" 

SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

:out $(OutDir)$(OutFile)

SELECT 
    'INSERT [State] ([StateId], [StateCd], [Description]) VALUES ('
    + CAST( [StateId] AS VARCHAR(2))
    + ', ''' + [StateCd] + ''''
    + ', ''' + [Description] + ''''
    + ');'
FROM [State];

GO  --this 'GO' is vital for this to work correctly.

:out stdout
```

--Graeme